# How can I add a new file to .csproj file without visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

How can I add a new file to `.csproj` from command prompt?

Comment: You can edit the .csproj with a text editor.

Comment: And why would you want to do such a thing? What is the goal?

Comment: This is a genuine question, I don't agree that it should have been closed.

Comment: With no context and very little information, it should remain closed.

Comment: I want to generate classes (following some kind of pattern) and attach those classes to several .csprojs

Comment: @AlexanderBeninski, that's an awful idea. What happens when you need to change the code in the class? A single class library complied into a DLL seems like a better approach.

Comment: @AlexanderBeninski, take a look at T4 templates to generate your code.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's any tool that will respond to an "add-project" command on the command-line to do this, but I think you could have luck creating a program/script to manipulate the XML content of csproj files directly.

The structure of a csproj file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="...">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- Properties which affect the build process -->
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- Groups of items to process -->
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

To add a C# code file to a project, you just need to add a `Compile` element to an `ItemGroup` element:

```
<Compile Include="{relative path to file}" />
```

If you use an existing project file as a template, this should be possible with a very simple XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way you can do it using Linq2Xml.  I've included a single and a list based method.  Oh, and like Casper said: you'll need to unload the project from VS before your program can edit it.  Then just reload it when done.

```
    private static void AddFilesToUnitTestProject(FileInfo[] files, string measureBaseDirPath, string measureDataDirSuffix)
    {
        var unitTestProjectPath = measureBaseDirPath + _unitTestProjectFile;
        var unitTestProjectFile = XDocument.Load(unitTestProjectPath);
        var itemGroup = unitTestProjectFile.Nodes()
                          .OfType<XElement>()
                          .DescendantNodes()
                          .OfType<XElement>().First(xy => xy.Name.LocalName == "ItemGroup");

        foreach (var fileInfo in files)
        {
            var xelem = AddProjectContent(measureDataDirSuffix + fileInfo.Name, unitTestProjectFile);
            itemGroup.Add(xelem);
        }
        unitTestProjectFile.Save(unitTestProjectPath);
    }

    private static void AddFileToUnitTestProject(string pathToAdd, string measureBaseDirPath, string measureDataDir)
    {
        var unitTestProjectPath = measureBaseDirPath + _unitTestProjectFile;
        var unitTestProjectFile = XDocument.Load(unitTestProjectPath);
        var itemGroup =
        unitTestProjectFile.Nodes()
                           .OfType<XElement>()
                           .DescendantNodes()
                           .OfType<XElement>().First(xy => xy.Name.LocalName == "ItemGroup");
        var xelem = AddProjectContent(pathToAdd, unitTestProjectFile);
        itemGroup.Add(xelem);
        unitTestProjectFile.Save(unitTestProjectPath);
    }

private static XElement AddProjectContent(string pathToAdd, XDocument doc) 
{ 
    XNamespace rootNamespace = doc.Root.Name.NamespaceName; 
    var xelem = new XElement(rootNamespace + "Content"); 
    xelem.Add(new XAttribute("Include", pathToAdd)); 
    xelem.Add(new XElement(rootNamespace + "CopyToOutputDirectory", "Always")); 
    return xelem; 
}
```

- Updated with AddProjectContent method

Comment: Could you please provide the code for AddProjectContent because your answer should fix my problem..

Comment: Sure no problem.  Here ya go:

        private static XElement AddProjectContent(string pathToAdd, XDocument doc)
        {
            XNamespace rootNamespace = doc.Root.Name.NamespaceName;
            var xelem = new XElement(rootNamespace + "Content");
            xelem.Add(new XAttribute("Include", pathToAdd));
            xelem.Add(new XElement(rootNamespace + "CopyToOutputDirectory", "Always"));
            return xelem;
        }

Answer (score 0):

.csproj files can be used as input into the MSBuild command line tool.

See the MSBuild reference:

[MS Build Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx)

And for example, this question.

[MSBuild — Use the .csproj file or roll your own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220075/msbuild-use-the-csproj-file-or-roll-your-own)

You can simply use a text editor to edit them and do anything MSBuild allows. If you insert custom build actions Visual Studio might warn a developer when the project is loaded that it contains custom actions, depending on what you do.

Answer (score -1):

Unload the project by right clicking it in solution explorer.
Edit the project by right clicking.
Add f.ex:

```
<Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
```

Comment: I would like to know the reason for the downvote, as this is a working answer to the question asked.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question explicitly says "without visual studio". Your answer doesn't respect that criteria.